# Why does git pull seem to pull in changes from another branch

Tags: git, github

I have a branch that I am working - feature1. When I am done making changes, I want to merge it into a release branch - release1. However, there are conflicts as release1 has changed since I started working. If I do a git pull while still on feature1, it pull in changes that have not been made on the feature1 branch and merges them. Why? Why are changes from other branches pulled and merged? Is it because feature1 was based on release1 and changes to release1 are therefore pulled in?

```
git checkout feature 1
{do some work}
git pull 
{changes are merged that were not made on feature1}
```

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. Usually the second command is `git merge`. The merge merges based on what the fetch fetched. Look at what fetch fetched; that will tell you what will be merged. I generally avoid `git pull` because I like to see what `git fetch` fetched *before* I choose what to do with that got fetched.

Comment: In any case, Git isn't about *branches*, but rather about *commits*. The fetch got some set of commits, and updated `origin/feature1` or whatever. The commits now reachable from `origin/feature1` (or whatever) are what will be merged. Use `git log` or `gitk` or your favorite commit-viewer to see what those commits are.

Comment: Why would git take changes made on another commit (branch) and pull them into my branch?

Comment: Is anyone else working on `feature1`?

Comment: No. It is a feature branch that I made and no one else has looked at it. Yet for some reason, if I do a git pull while on that branch, random changes come in. I assume that those are changes made to the base branch since I started feature1 but it doesn't look like it now.

Comment: If no one else is working on `feature1`, what is the point of saying `git pull`? What were you _trying_ to do by saying that?

Comment: Also, it might help if you would explain _how_ you made `feature1`. Can you explain that?

Comment: feature1 was created with release1 as its base - git checkout -b feature1 release1

Comment: Have you ever pushed `feature1`? How did you do it? What does `git status -sb` report?

Comment: Branches don't contain changes. Branches "contain" (really, *find*) commits; commits contain snapshots. Any one given commit is on zero or more branches at the same time. Many commits will be on many branches (depending on how many branch names you have); as you create new branches, most commits will be on the new branches. `git merge` will find the *merge base* commit and use that to find "ours" and "theirs" changes *since* that shared commit. To say much more, we'd need access to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `git pull`, you are "pulling" in commits from whatever branch your local branch is currently tracking. Usually you would track a remote branch by the same name as your checked out branch, but not necessarily. For example, if you have branch `feature1` checked out, typically you would be tracking `origin/feature1`. It sounds like in your case `feature1` is possibly setup to track `origin/release1` instead.

You can check which remote branch your checked out branch is tracking with `git status`. The status output will include what branch you're tracking, if you are tracking a branch, and will not mention it if you aren't tracking any branch. You can also see what every local branch is tracking with the command `git branch -vv`.

Once you've confirmed that your current branch is tracking the wrong branch, you can change the tracking branch by running this command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature1
```

Your problem should now be resolved.

**How did this happen?**

You mentioned in a comment that you created the branch by using the command:

```
git checkout -b feature1 release1
```

If you're correct, then I don't think it should have been tracking `origin/release1`. However, is it possible that you actually used this command instead (same as the previous but now with the word `origin` included):

```
git checkout -b feature1 origin/release1
```

In that case it would have tracked `origin/release1` by default! That is actually how I do it. I don't typically check out shared branches such as `main`, `master`, `develop`, `release*` since I don't need them; I just use their `origin/*` counterparts instead so I don't have to keep them up to date with a local copy. This also makes merging and rebasing simpler when you want to update your branch, since you can simply do:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/release1 # or merge if you don't like rebasing for some reason
```

I typically do that once or more times per day to update my branch with the latest, and it enables me to resolve any conflicts sooner than later.

When you create branches this way by using `origin`, it's best to also use the option to not track the remote:

```
git checkout -b feature1 origin/release1 --no-track
```

This way you won't accidentally track a branch you didn't intend to track, so pushing and pulling won't touch that branch. When you aren't tracking a branch yet, you can use `git push -u origin feature1` the first time you push or, once you've pushed, you can set the tracking branch with the command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature1
```

If you're absolutely sure you didn't use `origin/release1` when creating the branch, then you probably set the tracking branch another time and accidentally used the incorrect upstream branch name, perhaps at first push attempt.